# how to upload a photo to azure blob storage using cordova api?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, azure, phonegap-build, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a photo from mobile device to azure blob storage using Cordova api.  I just can't seem to get it to work.  Any idea will help out greatly.

Data uploaded to blob looks like this.

> start ---->
>
> --+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test"
>
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> Content-Length: 46785
>
> ���� ....
>
> <--- end

---

My code:

```
/*Cordova Camera API calls*/
$scope.takePic = function (type) {

    if (navigator.camera != undefined) {
        if (type == 'PHOTOLIBRARY')
            type = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
        else if (type == 'CAMERA')
            type = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;

        var options = {
            quality: 45,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: type,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        }
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options); 
    }
}

$scope.message = "Add an image";
var onSuccess = function (DATA_URL) {
    $scope.message = "Choose another image"; 
    $scope.postForm.onFileSelect = DATA_URL;
    $scope.$apply();
};
var onFail = function (e) {
    $scope.picData = null; 
    $scope.message = "On fail " + e;
};

//$scope.blobSasUrl is url to upload to azure blob storage
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onerror = fail;
xhr.onloadend = uploadCompleted;
xhr.open("PUT", $scope.blobSasUrl);
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-content-type', 'image/jpeg');
xhr.send($scope.postForm.onFileSelect);
```

Edit-----
    //I am using Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URI.  I also tried FILE_URI.

```
//This is not working (error)
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.result);  //nothing happens here
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);  //file is either DATA_URI or FILE_URI
```

Comment: I also tried FileReader object but reader.onloadend never gets triggered.  Not sure why...

Comment: You don't mention which error you get

Comment: Honestly i don't get any idea from your code but this post might help you. my application was done with the help of this post. follow it [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2014/12/15/epic-saga-final-chapter-success-or-how-to-upload-images-to-azure-from-a-cordova-app.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2014/12/15/epic-saga-final-chapter-success-or-how-to-upload-images-to-azure-from-a-cordova-app.aspx)

Comment: This is indeed wrong approach, you should upload image/file from Cordova to Simple HTTP Handler (server side php, apsx or python), which will store file on Azure using available APIs. How are you going to secure your Azure Blob Store keys, you can't distribute it with your app, it is not safe, you will face trouble when you will need to change them.

Comment: @Akash, thanks for your comment.  I am not sure if understand how azure blob storage work but there is no store key on client side so no worry there.  But you did make a good suggestion about posting it as multipart/form and take care the image from the server side.  What I am doing now works with web site but not with phonegap.  FileTransfer plugin force you to use multipart so that corrupts the uploaded photo.  I am able to upload but not as byte array but as encoded 64.  I may look into uploading a plain multipart submit.  Way I am doing is also recommended by MS people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by converting it to base64 string.  You can do this with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Create a blob storage service on your azure account, import the blob storage library into your website. Have the image send to your website hosted on Azure, then spin off a task to send it to your blob storage. The fact that you're using Cordova as a client is irrelevant. The server should not know who the platform client is, just how to handle the request.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Just FYI.  in order to post to azure blob storage, one needs to get a uniquely generated uri in order to post them.  so i get a unique post url from azure service as a call back result and I am able to do a PUT but image gets uploaded as 64 bit encoded format not byte array which Azure blob storage use.  Issue is that FileReader, reader.onloaded never gets triggered.  It doesn't generate error or nothing

Comment: Just want to add that I am able to upload byte array using a website without a problem, just not phonegap - ionic